# How to update a map in a single line with compute

Tags: java, hashmap

For a `HashMap<String, LongAdder> named counts`, how may I increment its value regardless of the key being present or not?

I've tried this

```
counts.compute(id, (k, v) -> v == null ? new LongAdder() : v.increment());
```

However `v.increment()` is a `void` method therefore that lambda does not agree with the `BiFunction<? super String, ? super LongAdder, ? extends LongAdder>` contract.

Comment: "However v.increment() is a void method" and thus you can't use it as an operand of the conditional operator, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `increment` outside the `compute`:

```
counts.computeIfAbsent(id, k -> new LongAdder()).increment();
```

Comment: Original code do not call `increment` if value is absent.

Comment: @talex this is true, but OP does say "how may I increment its value regardless of the key being present or not?" in the question. Given that the code in the question doesn't work, I'm taking the words as the intended behavior.

Comment: It may mean anything, OP didn't specify what "increment" means. According to code putting value to map for absent key is increment.

Comment: @talex I'll take the "accept" as an indication that this is what OP intended :)

Comment: Indeed the words described the intented behaviour